# TradingView, Is there any way to put all the balance to entry?

Tags: pine-script

For instance, I have 3000 dollars initial capital I want to put all the capital in every entry. And close/exit all the capital for every time.

If there is a loss, I will put the left capital to the next entry. Say if 2900 left after the close of first entry. I'll put 2900 to the next entry. Vice versa,  If there is 3100 left, I'll put 3100 to the next entry.

How can I achieve this?

What I tried:

```
initial_capital = 3000
strategy("test", overlay=true, 
       default_qty_type=strategy.cash, default_qty_value=initial_capital, currency=currency.USD
       initial_capital=initial_capital)

strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment='01')
```

In this way, it seemed putting 3000 every time, which was not I want.

### Update

Due to the answer from @brokeboynomore, I tried his approach, but got a strange error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment='01', qty=strategy.equity)
```

Whatever is your equity, it will use it as the trade quantity. default_qty_type must be
set to strategy.cash since strategy.equity is in cash

Edit:

```
currentBalance = strategy.initial_capital + strategy.netprofit
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment='01', qty=currentBalance)
```

This one I think is what you're looking for. It uses 100% of your current balance as the trade quantity.

**Edit: (8/15/2021)**

```
initial_capital = 3000
strategy("test", overlay=true, 
      default_qty_type=strategy.fixed, currency=currency.USD
      initial_capital=initial_capital)
balance = strategy.initial_capital + strategy.netprofit
balanceInContracts = balance/close
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, comment='01', qty=balanceInContracts)
```

This should fix the error. I converted balance into contracts and set `default_qty_type` to `strategy.fixed`.

Comment: Thanks for your awesome reply. from the plot(currentBalance), I think it's correct. but when I change `qty=currentBalance` there was an error. I updated on the question, please check. Thanks.

Comment: BTW, I think qty is the contracts for an order but not the amount of cash.

Comment: My bad, I think you might be right on the qty. Setting `default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity` and `default_qty_value=100` should do the trick if you're only taking one trade at a time, it will use 100 percent of your equity every trade.

Comment: I edited my answer. Let me know if it worked for you.